# Impersonate user (Switch to other user) functionality not working after closing browser

Tags: java, spring-security, grails3

I am unable to login as another user (Impersonate) once after closing the browser. Here are my config settings

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3'
```

**Gsp:**

`<g:link   uri="${request.contextPath}/login/impersonate?username=${s.username}" >Switch user</g:link>`

**application.groovy:**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/login/impersonate', access: ['ROLE_ADMIN','IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'] ],
    [pattern: '/**',             access: ['permitAll']]
    ....
    ]
```

**Error Screen:**

[image]

Note:
I have done with POST call as well, but still I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

By removing 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY' from [pattern: '/login/impersonate', access: ['ROLE_ADMIN'] ] then it works.